# Javascript - Use fetch on localhost with URL parameters

Tags: javascript, localhost, fetch-api, url-parameters

I have a NodeJS server running on port 3001 of my computer. I can use `fetch` to access a localhost endpoint, like this: `fetch("/api_endpoint")`.

However, I also want to include url parameters in my GET request.

Normally, I could include url parameters by doing this:

```
const url = new URL("localhost:3001")
const params = { sources: JSON.stringify(this.state.sources), timeRange: JSON.stringify(this.state.timeRange), minReacts: this.state.minReacts }
url.search = new URLSearchParams(params)
let data = await fetch(url)
```

However, this throws an error:

> Fetch API cannot load localhost:3001?sources=%5B%22Confessions%22%2C%22Summer+Confessions%22%2C%22Timely+Confessions%22%5D&timeRange=%5B%222017-01-12T23%3A35%3A07.666Z%22%2C%222019-01-12T23%3A35%3A07.667Z%22%5D&minReacts=20. URL scheme must be "http" or "https" for CORS request.

How can I use create a fetch request that works with localhost that also uses URL parameters?

Edit:

Adding `http://` to the front doesn't fix the problem.

> Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:3001/?sources=%5B%22Confessions%22%2C%22Summer+Confessions%22%2C%22Timely+Confessions%22%5D&timeRange=%5B%222017-01-13T00%3A00%3A17.309Z%22%2C%222019-01-13T00%3A00%3A17.310Z%22%5D&minReacts=20' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

Comment: Have you tried `const url = new URL("//localhost:3001")`

Comment: Typo: You forgot the `http://` or `https://` at the front of the URL.

Comment: @Quentin I tried adding `http://` to the front, but there was still an error. I'm working on fixing the new error now.

Comment: @Cue Trying that gave me an invalid URL.

Comment: Since request is being made from a page served on different port you need to implement CORS server side

Comment: "Adding http:// to the front doesn't fix the problem" — Yes, it did … you just had a second problem which fixing the first one revealed.

Comment: Vote to reopen. This is a CORS issue, not just the lack of http

Answer (score 23, accepted):

As per Quentin's advice, I needed to add `http://` in front of `localhost:3001`. The code became:

```
const url = new URL("http://localhost:3001")
```

Afterwards,  I needed to enable cors on my server in order to fix another error.

Because I was using express, I just ran `npm install cors` and then added the following 2 lines to my server:

```
const cors = require("cors")
app.use(cors())
```

Comment: Thank you Sir, Bt it is kinda weird that when directly writing url string to fetch as parameter it does not work. Probably URL class adds additional instances which makes it work.